# Formatting from Decimal to Exponential

Tags: bash, shell, numeric-data, floating-point

I have a data file abc.txt in the following format:

```
BALT 1
 54.500 -161.070
 3.95863757
 0.01691576
BARM 2
 -9.200 67.120
 4.07529868
 0.01951653
BKSR 3
 43.830 142.520
 4.08919819
 0.00587340
```

I need to convert it in the format:

```
BALT 1
 54.5000000 -161.070000
 0.3958637E+01
 0.1691576E-01
BARM 2
 -9.20000000 67.1200000
 0.4075298E+01
 0.1951653E-01
BKSR 3
 43.8300000 142.520000
 0.4089198E+01
 0.5873400E-02
```

The total spaces taken by the numbers in 2nd line should be 10 excluding -ve sign (e.g. 54.500 as 54.5000000 and -161.070 as -161.070000). The spaces for 3rd and 4rth line should be 13 (e.g. 3.95863757 as 0.3958637E+01). And BALT or BARM are variables, it may be another words with four characters.

> Thank you.

Comment: Would you accept `5.8734000e-03` instead of `0.5873400E-02`?

Comment: @terdon that is not what the OP ask for ...

Comment: @Archemar I know, that's why I'm asking. The two are completely equivalent but `5.8734000e-03` is much easier.

Comment: @terdon No, that should be like 0.5873400E-02

Comment: And more thing I should menion that BALT is variable like BARM or BKSR or BNKL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**version 3** use an awk file such as

```
function tenth(x) {
  u = x ; if ( u < 0 ) u = -x ;
  b=10 ;
  a=b-2 ;
  if ( u >= 10 ) {
  d=int(log(u)/log(10)) ;
  a=b-d-1 ;
  }
  printf "%*.*f",b,a,x ;
}
length($1) == 4 { print ; next  ;}
NF == 1 { d=int(log($1)/log(10)) ;if (d> -1) d++ ; printf " %.7fE%+03d\n",$1/(10^d),d ;}
NF == 2 { printf " " ; tenth($1); printf " " ; tenth($2) ; printf "\n" ;}
```

where

- `lengtht$1) == 4 { print ; next  ;}`  will leave alone line where first field is four letter (that may be 1234 though)
- `function tenth(x)` : define a function that adjust formating.
- `"%*.*f"` string adjust size/precision of `%f` conversion. first * is replaced by b, second * is replaced by a.
- `int(log()/log(10))` give decimal log that adjust representation to your specific need?

use it with

```
awk -f f.awk input
```

which give as a result

```
BALT 1
 54.5000000 -161.070000
 0.3958638E+01
 0.1691576E-01
BALT 2
 -9.20000000 67.1200000
 0.4075299E+01
 0.1951653E-01
BALT 3
 43.8300000 142.520000
 0.4089198E+01
 0.5873400E-02
 0.00000000 1.00000000
 -3.14150000 2.71828183
```

Comment: Thank you @Archemar for answering. Formatting from the 2nd script is looking good but that is not running in my PC. It is giving error:
`awk: f.awk: line 15: function tenthn never defined`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
awk '
  !/[[:alpha:]]/{
    if (NF == 1)
      $0 = sprintf(" %.7E", $0 * 10)
    else
      $0 = sprintf(" %.8f %.8f", $1, $2)
  }
  {print}' | sed '
    s/\([0-9.]\{10\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g
    s/\([1-9]\)\.\(.*\).E/0.\1\2E/'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get it without awk with:

```
while read line; do echo $line; read a; read b; read c;  printf "%.7f %.7f\n %.7e\n %.7e\n" $a $b $c; done < data.txt
```

However using printf this way can lead to some issues if you are using some locale using comma instead of period. In this case you should be able to fix it with:

```
while read line; do echo $line; read a; read b; read c; LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" printf "%.7f %.7f\n %.7e\n %.7e\n" $a $b $c; done < data.txt
```

Of course, in a script you should format it better with carriage return and indentation.

Comment: This isn't the output the OP asked for. They want the numbers on the lines after `BALT` to be 10 characters long (including the `.` apparently). Your approach will print numbers with 9 and 11 digits as well (`-9.2000000` and `-161.0700000` for example).

Comment: You are right; I didn't noticed this part of the question; I thought the original poster was asking about a tool for converting to exponential notation and I focused on that. I leave my answer in case it still has some interest to him/her however.